# django-activity-stream actions not displaying

Tags: django, django-models

I've just set django-activity-stream up but can't get it to display my actions when I goto the built in template mysite.com/activity/. Yet if I check the admin site I can see the actions have been saved as expected. I am using django-allauth for authentication/authorization

**myapp/Settings.py**

```
ACTSTREAM_SETTINGS = {
    'MODELS': ('auth.user', 'auth.group'),
    'MANAGER': 'actstream.managers.ActionManager',
    'FETCH_RELATIONS': True,
    'USE_PREFETCH': True,
    'USE_JSONFIELD': True,
    'GFK_FETCH_DEPTH': 0,
}
```

**myapp/receivers.py**

```
    from actstream import action
    @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def handle_user_logged_in(sender, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.get("request")
        user = kwargs['user']
        action.send(user, verb='logged in')
```

In the django-activity-stream `views.py` it seems `models.user_stream(request.user)` is returning empty. But I have no idea why.

**actstream/views.py**

```
  @login_required
    def stream(request):
        """
        Index page for authenticated user's activity stream. (Eg: Your feed at
        github.com)
        """
        return render_to_response(('actstream/actor.html', 'activity/actor.html'), {
            'ctype': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User),
            'actor': request.user, 'action_list': models.user_stream(request.user)
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Debugging from `models.userstream(request.user)` it seems I've found where it's returning no results:

**actstream/managers.py**

```
 @stream
    def user(self, object, **kwargs):
        """
        Stream of most recent actions by objects that the passed User object is
        following.
        """
        q = Q()
        qs = self.filter(public=True)
        actors_by_content_type = defaultdict(lambda: [])
        others_by_content_type = defaultdict(lambda: [])

        follow_gfks = get_model('actstream', 'follow').objects.filter(
            user=object).values_list('content_type_id',
                                     'object_id', 'actor_only')

        if not follow_gfks:
            return qs.none()
```

When I check the value at `q = self.filter` I can actually see all the correct "logged in" activities for the user I passed, however when it gets to `follow_gfks = get_model` because the user in question isn't following anyone else `follow_gfks` ends up being None and the query set `qs` gets deleted on the last line.

Why this works this way when im just trying to view my own users activity feed I have no idea.

Here's what a row from my actstream_action table looks like:

```
id                              1
actor_content_type_id           [fk]3
actor_object_id                 2
verb                            logged in
description                     NULL
target_content_type_id          NULL
target_object_id                NULL
action_object_content_type_id   NULL    
action_object_object_id         NULL
timestamp                       2013-09-28 12:58:41.499694+00
public                          TRUE
data                            NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get the action/activity list of the current logged in user by passing `user` to `actor_stream()` instead of `user_stream()`. But I have no idea why `user_stream` doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 1):

If it's your user that you want to show the actions for, you need to pass `with_user_activity=True` to `user_stream`; if it's for another user, you need to follow them first.